# Memory usage blows up but when I put a std::cout memory usage grows very very slowly

Tags: c++, memory, cout

I was just wondering what does my OS do if it ran out of memory and I wrote the following code.

```
int main() {
    int *p;
    while(1) {
        p = new int;
    }
}
```

But as I began to print the address of p and to my surprise the memory usage didn't blow up. It remains constant. And after each iteration the address of **p** is same as that of previous one.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int *p;
    while(1) {
        p = new int;
        std::cout << &p << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I was wondering how **`std::cout << &p << std::endl;`** is affecting memory?

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is smart enough to see that you're not doing anything with `p` other than print its address, so it simply optimizes out the memory allocation. Look at the generated assembly code to see what it does.

Comment: ... and that it seems not to do the same in the first case is irrelevant.  Memory allocation is not formally part of the externally visible behavior of the program.

Comment: Of course the address of `p` remains the same.  In both programs.  Assigning a *value* to `p` does not change its *address*.

Comment: So please clarify: how are you determining that the second program's memory usage remains constant?  Because you cannot glean that from the program's output.  If the output is all you are considering, then it is entirely plausible that the usage *does not* remain constant.

Comment: I suspect the main effect of the `std::cout <<` line is to slow down the execution of your program so much that its consumption of memory is less obvious.  Writing to stdout is *slooowww* compared to just allocating a heap buffer, e.g. 1000 times slower or more.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
std::cout << &p << std::endl;
```

does not print the address of the allocated memory, it prints the address of the variable `p`.

To print the address of the allocated memory drop the `&`.

```
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "&" notation, it means that you get the address of a variable which means the place you store this variable.

p is a 8 byte variable (64-bit machine) in your code, so if you out put the address of p, it's just the place the OS decide to put it, which remains constant.

Instead, what you want is to output the place where p's value points to.

So just output the value of p is enough

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int *p;
  while (1) {
    p = new int;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: @JohnBollinger tbh I don't know any way to actually see process memory allocation unless it's some tracing tools on Linux/bsd whichbimplant themselves into kernel. What we see is a representationof reserved\persistent memory use.

Comment: I think it might be due to the std::cout is a pending call, so it slower down the speed of memory allocation

Comment: I tested on my machine and used htop command in Linux to view the memroy usage. It came to a conclusion that std::cout slows down the loop... And the memory does not remain constant at all in both situations.